# Как получить часть строки, соответствующей регулярному выражению

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно с помощью регулярного выражения взять только то, что в квадратных скобках. Например:

```
example = [5 13 2 -7]
```

С помощью такого `"\\[.*\\]"` регулярного выражения я могу получить "[5 13 2 -7]", но мне нужно исключить эти скобки как бы, то есть получить "5 13 2 -7". Конечно, я бы мог удалять первый и последний символы, но вдруг можно их вообще не брать. ECMAScript синтаксис.

Comment: как-то так `"\[(.*)\]"`

Comment: или так `"(?<=\[).*(?=\])"`

Comment: ни первое, ни второе не помогает. К первому я и сам пришел, но оно "включает скобки", второе не работает, ни одного совпадения.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/eE1bD3/1

Comment: правда, я не знаю какая реализация регвыражений в с

Comment: ECMAScript. И на С++ оно (выражение) не работает..

Comment: Вопрос не в синтаксисе а в используемой библиотеке для работы с регулярками. Обычно библиотеки поддерживают не только возврат полного найденного совпадения, но и захват подстрок, которые возвращаются через отдельные переменные. Заключаете то что надо захватить в круглые скобки и библиотека регулярок вам возвращает это отдельно от основного результата, в составе так называемых "групп захвата". То что в perl зовется переменной $1 или в php будет лежать в соотв. элементе массива найденных подстрок. Для C библиотеки PCRE это возвращает функция `pcre_get_substring`

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно скобки добавить и заэкранировать слэш, который в обычной C++ строковой константе также специальный смысл имеет, то есть вместо `"\["` следует писать `"\\["`, чтобы в regex передать, или использовать `R"(` константы ([raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)), в которых не нужно слеш экранировать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  const std::string s = "example = [5 13 2 -7]";
  std::smatch match;
  std::regex re(R"(\[([^\]]*)\])");
  if (std::regex_search(s, match, re))
    std::cout << "match: '" << match[1] << "'\n";
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cc && ./a.out
match: '5 13 2 -7'
```

Я поменял регулярное выражение внутри на `[^]]*` вместо `.*`, чтобы результат скобки не содержал. Альтернативно, можно `.*?` использовать.